# A verb to describe a situation where someone communicate their meaning incorrectly

Tags: verbs

Is there a verb that describes a situation where one communicate their meaning incorrectly or in a way that is difficult to understand?
Something like "misconvey" or "misexpress" (I know these are not actual verbs)

Comment: Welcome to ELU! What have you found? What research have you done?

Comment: "Speaking" is pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

> **miscommunicate**
>   to fail to communicate clearly, fully, or accurately; to communicate incompletely or inaccurately. (1)

It was added to the *Oxford English Dictionary* in June 2002 as a new word (2). It apparently originated in the early 20th century (1).

**Sources**

(1) https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/miscommunicate

(2) http://public.oed.com/the-oed-today/recent-updates-to-the-oed/previous-updates/june-2002-update/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but "miscommunicate" seem a little stilted to me
Aren't there any alternatives??!

Comment: Perhaps a *miswording*? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138812/word-for-when-one-uses-the-wrong-word-in-a-sentence