# Is there a word for two or more words that look alike?

Tags: word-choice

What is the word for two similar words that can be confused?
e.g., immanent & imminent or proscription & prescription

The word describes frequently confused words, such as adapt, adopt, adept.

Comment: @SvenYargs: Why don't you write it as an answer? 'Confusible' is the best term so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word for when one uses the wrong word in a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138812/word-for-when-one-uses-the-wrong-word-in-a-sentence) **Confusables** aka **paronyms**. @RegDwight.

Comment: @SvenYargs From the OED: **Confusable** *Adj.* Capable of being, or liable to be, confused. **Also as n. plural (and with spelling -ible), things, esp. words, that may be confused.** -- **1864**   in Webster's Amer. Dict. Eng. Lang. ; and in later Dicts.  -- **1985**   Eng. Today Apr. 19/1   Much of this material deals with words or constructions which are often confused, and some even specialise in these ‘confusibles’. --- Post the answer - have this on me!

Answer (score 1):

These words look alike because they are of the same length and vary by a letter. Therefore, they are **orthographic neighbours** to each other.

> Orthographic neighbour—a word that differs from another word of the same length by only one letter.
>
> *Example*
>
> Given the word "cat", the words "bat", "fat", "mat", "cab", etc. are considered orthographic neighbors.
>
> — [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/orthographic_neighbour#:%7E:text=Noun,length%20by%20only%20one%20letter.)

Evidently, these (a) look similar and (b) especially with autocorrect, might be frequently confused for one another.

Answer (score 1):

Sven Yargs informs us that Adrian Room, in *The Penguin Dictionary of Confusibles (1979)*, calls them ... **confusibles**. His dictionary has useful entries for such similar-sounding terms as affect/effect, censor/censure, eruption/irruption, and Jacobean/Jacobin/Jacobite, but (for reasons unknown to me) it omits coverage of adapt/adept/adopt, eminent/immanent/imminent and prescription/proscription.

From the OED:

> **Confusable** Adj. Capable of being, or liable to be, confused. **Also as n. plural (and with spelling -ible), things, esp. words, that may be confused.**
>
> 1864 in Webster's Amer. Dict. Eng. Lang. ; and in later Dicts. --
>
> 1985 Eng. Today Apr. 19/1 *Much of this material deals with words or constructions which are often confused, and some even specialise in these ‘confusibles’.*

Answer (score -1):

If by "two similar words" you mean two words that sound alike, then the word for this is **homophone**. If you mean they are similar in the sense that they look alike (slightly different spelling), I don't think there is an exact word for that.

Merriam Webster [defines homophone](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homophone) as

> grammar: one of two or more words pronounced alike but different in meaning or derivation or spelling (such as the words to, too, and two)